# Angular 2 HTTP GET returning URL null

Tags: http, angular, get

I am trying to make a simple HTTP GET request using angular 2 with Typescript. I am getting a 404 error, with a null url. Shown below is my component file, and the error I am receiving.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BreadcrumbService } from './breadcrumbService';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  providers: [ BreadcrumbService],
  templateUrl: 'html/appList.html',
  styleUrls: ['css/list.css']

})
export class HealthComponent {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
      this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      .toPromise()
      .then((res: Response) => {
      console.log('RES: ', res);
      })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
      console.log('ERR!!: ', err);
    });
   }
}
```

The error message:

```
Response {_body: Object, status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found",     headers: Headers…}
 _body:Object
 headers:Headers 
 ok:false
 status:404
 statusText:"Not Found"
 type:2
 url:null
 __proto__:Body
```

Comment: What version of angular 2 do you use?

Comment: @galvan looks to be 2.0.0 beta .17 but i am using import @angular/http

Comment: I have the same issue - any luck?

Comment: @Yuvals I never solved it. I believe it was a problem with http imports.  I wasn't very far into the project, so i simply downloaded a started project with http already imported and working...

Comment: @MalindaMiller I believe I found the problem .. see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot` related issue. This happens when you load in-memory api, but trying to reach undefined url. The way to solve this is by setting `passThruUnknownUrl: true` in `app.module` config:

`InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, {passThruUnknownUrl: true}) ..`

Comment: Thank you so much, I was having the same problem and this is definately a working solution.  I'll have to look more into why the InMemory Module caused this behavior.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41752254/angular2-http-geturl-is-returning-404-on-a-valid-url-that-can-be-retrieved-usi/41752435?noredirect=1#comment70698057_41752435

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, it's a 404 error, analyse your request to the server. 404 error means that what you requested wasn't found.

About how you make the request, try ti use `.map` instead of `toPromise`.

Try to not make HTTP requests on the constructor, use ngOnInit instead.